# Renaming header of section of uitableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

How can i rename the title of section header on uitableviewcontroller outside of `titleForHeaderInSection` ?

Comment: Why you don't want to use `titleForHeaderInSection`?

Comment: I have to rename title in a function that triggered in viewdidload however titleForHeaderInSection is being triggered before that and useless for me. Or am i doing sth wrong ?

Comment: You can try one thing just add UIView and UILabel, use the label reference to update the title of the section

Comment: @BuntyMadan can you show an example please ?

Comment: As per my understanding you want to update the Title with reloading the table or the delegate call. right? so my point is in `viewForHeaderInSection` create `UIView` and add `UILabel` so just use the label reference for updating the title

Comment: Because calling `reloadData` is too mainstream?

Comment: If for some reason you can't use `reloadData`, then an easy way is to use a custom view for your header. You can easily get the header view with: `tableView.headerViewForSection(_:)` and change your label there.

Comment: @Eendje cannot find where i change in headerViewForSection ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without using `titleForHeaderInSection`

- Make dynamic array 1st object for header custom cell then objects for tableview cell... and so on
- Draft custom cell for header
- While screen appear use `cellForRowAtIndexPath` with condition as per header custom cell and objects for table view
- At particular event change array value for header custom cell then use `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths()`

So it will reload only index given in `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths()`, no need for `reloadData()`.

Comment: But tableview is not dynamic, it is static

Comment: No matter, make static array with some objects for header custom cell and some for table view custom cell.

By using reloadRowsAtIndexPaths() you can only reload that particular index.

Answer (score 0):

So as per the question statement update title without reloading or delegates just using the label reference for updating the title for section.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
let view = UIView() //set the frame accordingly 
let label = UILabel() //set the frame accordingly
//make it global and use it reference for updating the title of the section
view.addSubview(label)
return view
}
```

I am not using `Xcode` so please validate just writing code roughly

Answer (score 0):

```
// If only section 2 has a header
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    return section == 2 ? updateHeader(section) : nil
}

func updateHeader(section: Int) -> CustomHeader {
    let header = (tableView.footerViewForSection(section) ?? tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier("customHeader")) as! CustomHeader

    // Set up your header

    return header
}

// Change text in header
let header = updateHeader(2).customLabel.text = "Your custom text"
```

Just a small example. Be aware that when the tableview gets reloaded, it will change back to your default setup of your header. So be sure you handle that within your own code.

Comment: What is the CustomHeader ?

Comment: A subclass of `UITableViewHeaderFooterView`. You can use a normal `UIView` or `UITableViewCell` as well, but then you'll have to use other methods to get the header.